# Animated container in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, containers, flutter-animation

i want to achieve this functionality .when one container is in front the other two should be half on screen and little bit blured and when animation time out of one container,next one will gradually increase its size and show in front .This process continues.
Please Guide

This image has been taken from the appliation

[image]

Comment: try PageView.builder & set controller's viewPortFraction as u like (controller: PageViewController( viewportFraction: 0.8 ) )

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_carousel_widget

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this type of view, Try this package [`carousel_slider`](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) or [`flutter_carousel_widget`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_carousel_widget).

Happy Codding!!